# Ignite TcpDiscoverySpi fails with Critical system error with SocketTimeout due to 'accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0..'

Tags: docker, ignite, gridgain

With Ignite 2.7.6 when trying to bring up an embedded ignite server node (in a spring boot app) on a docker bridge network **with simple configuration** the server start up fails with the below error,

```
[10:16:16] Ignite node started OK (id=e7276b83)
[10:16:16] >>> Ignite cluster is not active (limited functionality available). Use control.(sh|bat) script or IgniteCluster interface to activate.
[10:16:16] Topology snapshot [ver=1, locNode=e7276b83, servers=1, clients=0, state=INACTIVE, CPUs=1, offheap=0.1GB, heap=0.4GB]
mediation-service - [INFO ] 10:16:16.981 [main] com.**.**.perfmon.common.spring.EmbeddedIgnite    - ====>>> Activating Ignite Cluster
mediation-service - [WARN ] 10:16:17.383 [exchange-worker-#49] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager     - Started write-ahead log manager in NONE mode, persisted data may be lost in a case of unexpected node failure. Make sure to deactivate the cluster before shutdown.
[10:16:17] Started write-ahead log manager in NONE mode, persisted data may be lost in a case of unexpected node failure. Make sure to deactivate the cluster before shutdown.
mediation-service - [ERROR] 10:16:21.982 [tcp-disco-srvr-#3] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi        - Failed to accept TCP connection.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$TcpServer.body(ServerImpl.java:5845)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$TcpServerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:5763)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
mediation-service - [WARN ] 10:16:21.982 [RMI TCP Accept-19887] sun.rmi.transport.tcp   - RMI TCP Accept-19887: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=19887] throws
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:394)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:366)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
mediation-service - [WARN ] 10:16:21.982 [RMI TCP Accept-0] sun.rmi.transport.tcp       - RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=33254] throws
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
        at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:394)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:366)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
mediation-service - [ERROR] 10:16:21.984 [tcp-disco-srvr-#3]    - Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=NoOpFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out]]
```

Below are the relevant config,

Ignite config xml snippet:

```
....
....
<property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean
                class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
</property>
....
....
```

docker-compose snippet:

```
services:
  ***-mediation-service:
    image: ***/mediation-service:latest
    build: .
    environment:
    - PERCENTAGE_OF_RAM_FOR_HEAP=80.0
    - SERVICE_NAME=mediation-service
    - SERVICE_PORT=9887
    - IGNITE_TCP_DISCOVERY_ADDRESSES=localhost
    - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=19887
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=19887
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST_IP
  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
  -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=29887
    ...
    ...
    networks:
      - something-mediation-network

networks:
  something-mediation-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 186.30.240.0/24
```

Any one knows whats going on here?

Thanks
Muthu

UPDATE (11/13/2020): I tried the same with 2.9.0 as suggested by @alamar but with the same result..please see below

```
mediation-service - [ERROR] 01:03:16.871 [tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3-#50] org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi   - Failed to accept TCP connection.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$TcpServer.body(ServerImpl.java:6620)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$TcpServerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:6543)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58)
mediation-service - [WARN ] 01:03:16.871 [RMI TCP Accept-19887] sun.rmi.transport.tcp   - RMI TCP Accept-19887: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=19887] throws
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:394)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:366)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
mediation-service - [WARN ] 01:03:16.871 [RMI TCP Accept-0] sun.rmi.transport.tcp   - RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=33351] throws
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:394)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:366)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
mediation-service - [ERROR] 01:03:16.876 [tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3-#50]   - Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=NoOpFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out]]
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:565)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:533)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$TcpServer.body(ServerImpl.java:6620)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$TcpServerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:6543)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58)
mediation-service - [WARN ] 01:03:17.271 [tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3-#50] org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheDiagnosticManager    - Page locks dump:
```

UPDATE (11/18/2020):

I have another update which is that if i use Java 8 instead of Java 11 i don't see this issue during cluster activation & things work.

So i suspect this has something to do with the underlying java library use/dependencies..

Comment: Note that i initially tried specifying 'localhost' directly in the config xml file with the same result..

Comment: Have you tried `2.9.0`?

Comment: @alamar Not yet, do you think this has a fix in 2.9.0?

Comment: It's worth checking

Comment: @alamar checked & got the same result..updated the description above..

Comment: @lmk have you tried setting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true?

Comment: @SemyonDanilov I already had that setting unfortunately...updated the snippet above to show that..

Comment: @lmk do you, by any chance, have iptables (and netfilter) up and running on your machine? It could be meddling with docker’s ports.

Comment: @SemyonDanilov thank you, i checked that, i don't have any iptables or firewalld & also i see the same issue in all my peer's machines aswell.

Comment: @lmk, ok, just to make sure: the problem only arises while using docker?

Comment: @SemyonDanilov I suspect so, but sorry haven't checked that yet...but i have another update to report which is that if i use Java 8 instead of Java 11 that i was using it works fine, so it must be something to do with the underlying library dependency behavior..

Comment: Oh, in that case: have you exported all the needed modules and  peohibited tlsv1.3? Like this: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java#running-ignite-with-java-11-or-later

Comment: @SemyonDanilov thanks once again for that one...don't know how i missed that..will try that one out...on tls1.3 there is no ssl used & its seen in a single node

Comment: @lmk any luck fixing it?

Comment: Hi @SemyonDanilov , sorry i got pulled into another work item but will get to this later this week & will make sure to update you on this thread.

Answer (score 4):

The error means that the socket has a timeout set, and no incoming message was received during the timeout.

The funny thing is that the socket that Ignite creates has no timeout! Which suggests a bug somewhere...

... and this time it's in Java: [JDK-8237858](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8237858). The bug description says that the `accept` can be interrupted by a signal (which is expected), and that causes Java to throw the error (which is the bug).

According to the OpenJDK Jira, this doesn't affect Java 8. Fixed in Java 16, and also doesn't affect Java 13 with default settings.

I don't see mentions of fixes in Java 11 maintenance releases though.

UPDATE: There is a [fix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-15767) for this in 2.12. Basically, Ignite had to embed a workaround for the bug in its own code.

Comment: Thank you @Stanislav Lukyanov . Unfortunately we are using Java 11 & can't upgrade :(..need to check on the maintenance fixes..

Comment: Thank you very much @Stanislav Lukyanov, this was a difficult one to catch. Do you know of some workaround? Because although upgrade is an option for us, new JDK versions doesn't seem to be fully supported with Ignite.

Comment: @lujop There is a fix for this in 2.12: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-15767. Basically, Ignite had to embed a workaround for the bug in its own code.